# jQuery live() removing iPhone touch event attributes?

Tags: jquery, iphone, touch, live

I am binding live events on links in my [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) app. The event does fire successfully (confirmed by `alert()`ing), but it seems any touch data is not attached to the event object like it should be. This happens on all touch events - `touchstart`, `touchmove`, and `touchend`.

```
$('a').live('touchend', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(event.touches.length); // event.touches should be populated!
});
```

Any ideas? Am I SOL with jQuery.live()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The touch events are not currently supported by [Events/live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live).

From the documentation:

> Possible event values: click,
>   dblclick, mousedown, mouseup,
>   mousemove, mouseover, mouseout,
>   keydown, keypress, keyup
>
> Currently not supported: blur, focus,
>   mouseenter, mouseleave, change, submit

You might want to consider trying to use click if that will suit your needs, or you can switch to using [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery), which probably will support it. (livequery is what live was originally based on, I'm not sure why it doesn't support all of the same events)

Comment: I'll try out livequery, thanks. Figured as the touch events were getting caught OK that they were fairly supported, but I guess something extra has to happen to pass along all the event attributes.

Comment: I believe livequery uses timers and that is why it can support so much more.  The jQuery team used a different method that is more efficient, but also limited.

Answer (score 16):

Actually, you can use the .live method. You don't have the event.touches property because of how jQuery handles events internally. In order to "fix" events, jQuery clones the event. In doing so, it only copies over a limited number of properties for performance reasons. However, you can still access the original event object via the event.originalEvent property.

So your example code would need to look like the following:

```
$('a').live('touchend', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.originalEvent.touches.length);
});
```

Here are the properties that are copied over: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L411

Comment: This appears to be true in the new jQuery 1.4. It wasn't the case in 1.3.

Comment: jQuery 1.3.x had the same behavior, to copy over a set number of common properties and expose the original event as an originalEvent property. Relevant source: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.3/src/event.js#L282