# Recording touch coordinates in canvas animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas, touch

I'm making this mini-game in HTML5 canvas using javascript's requestAnimationFrame.

```
 function animate() {
  frame = requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  render();
 }
```

It's destined to be a Cordova application, so I have to record touch input.
The game starts when the screen is pressed

```
 document.addEventListener('touchstart',run);
```

It stops when the finger is removed.

I'm now looking for a way to record the touch's x and y coordinates, in order to display the finger's position smoothly on the screen.

So I was thinking about getting the x and y coordinates, and making an arc on this place in the 
    render()
function

But how could I permanently get these coordinates, or is there another way of doing this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this..

[Is there an equivalent to e.PageX position for 'touchstart' event as there is for click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780837/is-there-an-equivalent-to-e-pagex-position-for-touchstart-event-as-there-is-fo)

```
 $(document).on('touchstart', 'body', function(e) {
      var xPos = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
     var yPos = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
    });
```