# Handling iPad touch events for draggables/droppables (undefined changedTouches)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, touch-event

I am trying to get jQuery drag/drop to work nicely with iPad touch events. I found this code on the internet:

```
function touchHandler(event)
{
    var touches = event.changedTouches,
        first = touches[0],
        type = "";
    switch (event.type)
    {
        case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
        case "touchmove": type = "mousemove"; break;
        case "touchend": type = "mouseup"; break;
        default: return;
    }

    //initMouseEvent(type, canBubble, cancelable, view, clickCount, 
    //           screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, 
    //           altKey, shiftKey, metaKey, button, relatedTarget);

    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                              first.screenX, first.screenY,
                              first.clientX, first.clientY, false,
                              false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

    first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

It appears to work fine if I attach the touchHandler to the `document` touchstart/move/end, but then no native zooming/scrolling on the iPad is allowed, so I am trying to just attach this handler to the draggables themselves.

The issue that I am seeing with this is that `event.changeTouches` is always undefined for some reason, as you can witness in http://jsfiddle.net/myLj2/1/ . I can't come up with a reason why a touch event will always have an undefined `changeTouches` property and because of it, this code won't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9):

I figured it out after discovering [Does jQuery preserve touch events properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183872/does-jquery-preserve-touch-events-properties).

It turns out that the jQuery event doesn't copy over the `changeTouches` property, so you have to either use jQuery's `originalEvent` property or skip jQuery all together and bind with a function like `addEventListener`