# iPhone jQuery click event

Tags: jquery, iphone, click

I have a simple click event attached to a number of anchors on my web app.

```
$('a.heading').live("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   //do my stuff
});
```

It's not rocket science. However on my iPhone the click doesn't register. It would appear it uses the touch handler for iPhone (iPad, Android etc are all fine).

I've seen a couple of tutorials but cannot seem to get my head around it. Is there not a one liner that I can use that jQuery is so usually good at?

Comment: iPhone uses touch not click :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705937/document-click-not-working-correctly-on-iphone-jquery

Comment: Similar Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671498/jquery-live-removing-iphone-touch-event-attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isiPhone = (userAgent.indexOf('iphone') != -1 || userAgent.indexOf('ipod') != -1) ? true : false;
clickEvent = isiPhone ? 'tap' : 'click';
```

Comment: looks hacky. Looks like you're aiming at a moving target.

Comment: There are also other mobile devices besides iPhone.  The OP was simply stating his particular case.