# AddEventListener for dynamic elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

On my page, when you swipe right on an element, the element will move. I have the following code to handle these swipes:

```
window.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, false);
window.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove, false);
```

Problem is, it's not just affecting the elements that I want to be swipe-able. Instead, if I swipe anywhere on the page, it will run `touchMove`. To fix this, I tried:

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");
content.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, false);
content.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove, false);
```

This sort of worked, but when a div was shown (via user interaction) over `#content`, the events would still fire.

Another solution that I considered was binding these events to the elements in `#content`, the ones that should have swiping enabled. Problem is, these elements are added to the page dynamically, so when the function above is called on page load, the elements aren't accounted for. I then looked to using jQuery's `.on()` method, like so:

```
$("#content .row").on("touchmove", touchMove, false);
```

But that's not calling `touchMove` at all.

Is there a better way to do all of this? Does it make sense that `touchMove` would get called on an element that's not a child of `#content` when  the event listener is assigned to only `#content`?

Comment: you are missing closing quotes on the jquery version "#content .row"

Comment: Fixed. That's not the problem though, I just quickly wrote that and missed the quote.

Comment: it's `$(document).on(event, selector, handler)` so you for you `$(document).on("touchmove", selector, touchMove)` where you have to substitute selector by the element you want to move (possibly `.row`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way by attaching event to document and providing filter for your required elements.

```
$(document).on("touchmove", "#content .row", touchMove);
```

Edit as per comments, you can get event this way

```
$(document).on("touchmove", "#content .row", function(event){
       alert(event.target.id);
});
```

Comment: When I was writing my question, I wrote that out too quickly, and because of that, missed the quote. That's not the problem though.

Comment: This works, but the only problem is that `event.target` does not seem to be copied over into the function. I tried to follow the solutions here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671498/jquery-live-removing-iphone-touch-event-attributes, but even within the function, `console.log(event.originalEvent.touches.length);` is logging undefined.

Comment: Also, I'm looking at the code again, and having a simple `console.log()` within the code above still runs when I swipe on any element. This is really weird...

Comment: I actually think I got it working. Also, `even.target` works after I removed the `event` from `setFavorite(event);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#content .row").on("touchmove", touchMove, function(){
   // Your code here
});
```

The `false or true` value after the selector is not required here as most of the events are attached using `event bubbling.`. You can omit that and write up the handler in this case